# How to disable clicks detection in a CheckBox that's wrapped by an InkWell in Flutter

Tags: flutter, checkbox, ontap

I have those 4 `Inkwell()`, inside each of them is a `CheckBox()`,
In the `onTap:`  property of the `InkWell()` I assigned an unnamed function that does some logic.
When I click on the checkbox, the 'onTap' property of the parent `InkWell` isn't invoked.

What I wanna do, is when I click on the `CheckBox`, the `onTap` of the parent widget `InkWell` get called, so it's like disabling the `CheckBox` onChanged property, and letting it just like an unclickable widget.

Note: By assigning `null` to the `onChanged` property of `CheckBox`, the widget still absorb the click, so the `onTap` property of `InkWell` doesn't get called.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () { /* DO SOMETHING */},
  child: Row(
    children: [
      SizedBox( /* The flag icon */ ),
      Text( /* The language name */ ),
      Checkbox(
        onChanged: null,
        value: (selectedLanguage == widget.id) ? true : false,
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your `Checkbox` widget inside an `IgnorePointer`

```
IgnorePointer(
      child: Checkbox(
        value: selectedLanguage == widget.id,
        onChanged: (v) {
          // This won't get called
        },
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks it's working